# responsive design breakpoints

Tags: html, css, responsive

I am trying to get away from bootstrap, and actually control my breakpoint myself. Before I go on with learning, I would like to know if I am on the right track. So is it correct to do it like this:

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">
        <img src="banner.png"/>
            <section id="left-column">
                <p>This is the left column</p>
            </section>
            <aside id="right-column">   
                <p>This is the right column</p>
            </aside>
    </div>
    <!-- /Container -->

</body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
#container {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

#left-column {
    width: 700px;
    float: left;
    background-color: red;
}
#right-column {
    width: 260px;
    float: left;
    background-color: blue;
}

/* Tablet & Computer */
@media screen and (max-width:959px) {
    #container {
        width:100%;
    }
    #left-column {
        width: 70%;
    }
    #right-column {
        width: 30%;
    }
    img {
        width: 100%
    }
}   

/* Phone */
@media screen and (max-width:640px) {
    #left-column {
        width: 100%;
    }
    #right-column {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
/* Stop Scaling */
@media screen and (max-width:320px) {
    #container {
        width: 320px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's a good / bad way to use media queries, just the way you want it to :)

Bootstrap helps you with that by providing different breakpoint to apply to mobile/tablet/desktop and also different class names to help you with your layout style but you can do it from your own by using the breakpoints you want without Bootstrap. (See medias queries information about Bootstrap here : http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries )

So your way to do it is correct. Just close the last bracket here :

```
/* Stop Scaling */
@media screen and (max-width:320px) {
    #container {
        width: 320px;
    }
}
```

Also, I prefer to use fluid width (%) with mobile because it will takes the full width of the screen. In the case of your last media query, the width selected is quite useless (I don't know a lot of devices who go down 320px width)

See here common devices used to help you select media queries : 
http://mydevice.io/devices/

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer.

Comment: Can I just ask a last thing. You were taking about the fluid. If I wanted to give my container a 100% width, so I made sure that all it fills all the screen. How could I do that? Give it 100% instead of max-width:959px?

Comment: In your media query, you can overwrite the width of your container. `max-width: 959px` is part of the query, in your query you can set a 100% width to your container to make it works. But I see it's already working like this :)

Comment: What about if I wanted the container to be 100% on all devices. The same like fluid does in bootstrap. Like this fx: http://neighborhoodfilmcompany.com/ As it is right now, the page is centered in the middle.

Comment: Then define fluids dimensions like this (with your code) : https://jsfiddle.net/ort7o2br/3/

Comment: So the only reason that my banner is not going all the way now, is because it is only 700px wide?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109333/discussion-between-vincent-g-and-julie24).

Answer (score 1):

You can get rid of Bootstrap but you can use their approach in break points

which is

**Extra small devices Phones** `<768px`

**Small devices Tablets** `≥768px`

**Medium devices Desktops** `≥992px`

**Large devices Desktops** `≥1200px`

you need to specify grid systems for your columns instead of hard coded columns widths

like

```
.col1{
  width:8.33333333%
}

.col2{
  width:16.66666667%
}

.col3{
  width:25%
}

.col4{
  width:33.33333333%
}

.col5{
  width:14.666667%
}

.col6{
  width:50%
}

.col7{
  width:58.33333333%
}

.col8{
  width:66.6666667%
}

.col9{
  width:75%
}

.col10{
  width:83.33333333%
}

.col11{
  width:91.6666666%
}
.col12{
  width:100%
}
```

Finally you have to define rows for your columns to avoid conflicts in height due to floating of the columns

```
.row{
  margin-left:-15px;
  margin-right:-15px;
 }
.row{:after{
  content:'';
  display:block;
  clear:both
}
.col{   //general properties of columns
  padding:15px;
  float:left; 
}
```

**Update:** if you didn't clear the floats after `row` class via `clear:both;` you will find that the height of columns container is always 0 even if columns has contents this because the float subtract the height of the element from the height of the container

also you need to give it `margin-left:-15px;` and `margin-right:-15px;` to keep the first and last columns of the row align with the content of the page

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer. I have to study a little bit a bout giving the col width, instead of hardcoding them.

Comment: Peter are you still on the threat? I find this approach quite interresting after I have been looking at it a long time. I am not quite sure what the defining of rows{:after does?. So every time I make a new row, and set my class to that column I would like?

Comment: `<div class="row">
  <div class="col12">Main Picture</div>
</div>
`
What that be correct?

Comment: @Julie24 please check the updates in my answer I hope I clear it for you, sorry for being late

Answer (score 0):

You can do it that way, but I would suggest using less or sass since it will otherwise be quite tedious (and you should definitely use autoprefixer too!).  Technically, you should probably style classes and not ids since it will be less disruptive. You might want to add a min-width, and you should probably verify that 70% + 30% can't ever be more than 100% due to rounding issues.

Flexbox is the new/cool way of doing grids, see e.g. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/, but that's just until we get proper grid layouts in css (e.g. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/).

Comment: Thank you. I will just sit and look and the flexbox now